# Mac cli to convert yaml to json

Tags: json, yaml

is there a quick way to convert bunch of yaml files to json files. I looked at yaml2json and it is not working (throws some exception)

Thanks

Comment: Better share these exceptions

Answer (score 35):

Adding answer because there's no answer for the latest version for yq (except in comments).

```
brew install yq

yq -j eval test.yaml
```

Or, newer syntax:

```
yq -o=json eval test.yml
```

Comment: And even that is already deprecated. Seems to be a pretty moving target. It's `yq -o=json eval test.yml` now.

Answer (score 11):

Use the real yq (not python yq) from https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

`brew reinstall yq`

Then run:

`/usr/local/bin/yq eval deployment.yaml -o=json -P > deployment.json`

Meaning of the arguments, from `--help`:

```
  -P, --prettyPrint           pretty print, shorthand for '... style = ""'
  -o, --output-format string  [yaml|y|json|j|props|p|xml|x] output format type. (default "yaml")
```

Comment: `r` didn't work for me, shouldn't it be `eval` (in the recent `yq` version, at least)?

Comment: Im on the newer version `yq version 4.7.1` and yes should be `eval` and this version does not have a `r` cli flag/option.

Comment: The `mikefarah/yq` went thought so many incompatible cli usage / flag changes I got burned on, I gave up on it. Have been using JQ wrappers, such as [Blacksmoke16/oq](https://github.com/Blacksmoke16/oq) or [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (Python pip) with much success, since they just convert into JSON and pass all the processing to JQ.

Comment: I've edited this answer to use the latest parameters (from yq v4.25.2)

Answer (score 7):

You could pipe your YAML to this (requires having pyYAML installed)

```
python -c 'import yaml; import json; import sys; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)));'
```

Answer (score 1):

With current releases of `yq` (v4.24.5):

`yq eval -o json my.yaml > my.json`

Note that (as of `4.18.1`) `eval` is the default command when none is supplied to `yq`, which means that this works perfectly fine, as well.

`yq -o json my.yaml > my.json`

Answer (score 1):

To riff on [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65954549/1394353), if you have Python and PyYaml then you can define a quick bash/zsh (yes, it works on both) function:

```
jconvyamljson(){
    if [[ ! -f $1 ]]; then
        >&2 echo need to provide an existing file to convert
        exit 1
    fi

    cat $1 | python -c 'import yaml; import json; import sys; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)));' 
}
```

Usage is then as simple as :

piping to yaml for formatting/processing if needed

```
jconvyamljson directive.Usergroup_list.yaml | jq .cssc_table

"table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
```

or, handling a missing file:

```
jconvyamljson this-file-doesnt-exist  | jq .cssc_table
need to provide an existing file to convert
```

Answer (score 0):

Install yq , yaml2json wont work for mac

```
brew install yq
```

Then use it:

```
yq -o=json test-env.yml > test-env.json
```

Here test-env.json is the output file